# Is changing memory within warp defined?

Tags: cuda, synchronization

For now I use atomicAdd to change some memory cell. I am interested is the behaviour of changing the same memory (without atomicAdd) within warp defined? I have particular architecture in mind -- Fermi.

Let's say I have pointer to memory, the same for all 32 threads (same block), there is no more threads at all, and I perform:

```
++(*ptr);
```

Is this undefined? Defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ptr` refers to the same global or shared memory location across threads in a warp, then the behavior is undefined.  That is to say, the indicated contents (i.e. `*ptr`) will be undefined, when the operation is complete.

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind, thank you very much for clarification.